# ReCaptcha not working in FireFox

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am having a reCaptcha problem on my register.php page.  This is working fine in IE but not in firefox and some other web browsers.  I am getting the error that "Undefined index:  recaptcha_challenge_field" and "recaptcha_response_field" when using Firefox.  Trying to track down the problem I tried to W3 validate but and running into this and again I am stumped. Are the two related?

Errors found while checking this document as XHTML 1.0 Transitional!
document type does not allow element "form" here

The element named above was found in a context where it is not allowed. This could mean that you have incorrectly nested elements -- such as a "style" element in the "body" section instead of inside "head" -- or two elements that overlap (which is not allowed).

One common cause for this error is the use of XHTML syntax in HTML documents. Due to HTML's rules of implicitly closed elements, this error can create cascading effects. For instance, using XHTML's "self-closing" tags for "meta" and "link" in the "head" section of a HTML document may cause the parser to infer the end of the "head" section and the beginning of the "body" section (where "link" and "meta" are not allowed; hence the reported error).

```
     <table class="formFont" width="600" align="center" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" style="border:#999 1px solid; background-color:#FBFBFB;">
    <form action="register.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><font color="#FF0000"><?php print "$errorMsg"; ?></font></td>
      </tr>       
      <tr>
        <td width="116" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">User Name:</td>
        <td width="452" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="username" type="text" class="formFields" id="username" value="<?php print "$username"; ?>" size="32" maxlength="20" />
          <span id="nameresponse"><span class="textSize_9px"><span class="greyColor">Alphanumeric Characters Only</span></span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="116" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">First Name:</td>
        <td width="452" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="firstname" type="text" class="formFields" id="firstname" value="<?php print "$firstname"; ?>" size="32" maxlength="20" />
          <span ><span class="textSize_9px"><span class="greyColor">Alphanumeric Characters Only</span></span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="116" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Last Name:</td>
        <td width="452" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="lastname" type="text" class="formFields" id="lastname" value="<?php print "$lastname"; ?>" size="32" maxlength="20" />
          <span ><span class="textSize_9px"><span class="greyColor">Alphanumeric Characters Only</span></span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Email Address:</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="email1" type="text" class="formFields" id="email1" value="<?php print "$email1"; ?>" size="32" maxlength="48" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Confirm Email:</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="email2" type="text" class="formFields" id="email2" value="<?php print "$email2"; ?>" size="32" maxlength="48" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Create Password:</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="pass1" type="password" class="formFields" id="pass1" size="32" maxlength="16" />
          <span class="textSize_9px"><span class="greyColor">Alphanumeric Characters Only</span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Confirm Password:</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="pass2" type="password" class="formFields" id="pass2" size="32" maxlength="16" />
        <span class="textSize_9px"><span class="greyColor">Alphanumeric Characters Only</span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php          require_once('recaptchalib.php');
                  $publickey = "6LcL98wSAAAAAK93qqBkJfF0ltsFSieV3inlMdY7"; 
                  echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);        ?><br />
          <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Sign Up!" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the form opening tag outside of the table opening tag, and close up the form after the table's closing tag. Technically, only tbody, tr, and td tags should go in a form

Comment: glad i was able to help :)